# Is the relationship between Dathomiri and Rancors still canon?

Tags: star-wars

In the Legends canon, Rancors originated from the planet Dathomir, and the Dathomiri witches - as well as their evil counterparts the Nightsisters - had a symbiotic relationship with the beasts. The witches considered the Rancors to be part of their family, something akin to a beloved pet, and often rode them as mounts through the jungles of Dathomir.

In the new Disney canon, the status quo on Dathomir seems to have been changed. The landscape is no longer depicted as Earth-like jungle & swamps, the Nightsisters are now the ones in charge, and no rancors have been shown. **Does this relationship still exist? And if not, where do Rancors come from now?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mostly not

Wookieepedia [suggests](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rancor) that rancors are still native to Dathomir. They apparently appear in the canon video game *Star Wars: Galactic Defense*. Other than that, I can’t find any canon information on the relationship between Nightsisters and rancors.

What is certain, though, is that rancors are no longer *exclusively* native to Dathomir. There [are](http://www.starwars.com/databank/rancor) subpopulations on Felucia and Teth, known as “jungle rancors.”